# Angular UI + UI Router: How to inherit Resolved states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I have a parent state with 3 child states. The parent state retrieves data using promises and returns resolved data in an object (named 'data') so it is accessible to controller and views. Some child states need the resolved parent data also to define their own object named data. But it seems that when transitioning from sibling states their resolves are never reached (a breakpoint in the corresponding state definition never gets hit).

In short: when transferring from state 'settings.account.person' to sibling state 'settings.account.password' I want the resolve statement to be executed. Currently it is not being hit at all...

States:

```
.state('settings.account', {
    url: '/account'
    ,resolve: {
        menu: ['menu','MenuService', function (menu,MenuService) {
            return MenuService.retrieveSubMenuByParentUrl(menu,'/settings/account');
        }],
        account: ['UserManagementService',function(UserManagementService) {
            return UserManagementService.account();
        }],
        data: ['menu',function (menu) {
            return {menu:menu};
        }]
    }
    ,views: {
        'setting@settings': {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/settings/account/views/tabpanel.html'
            ,controller: 'AccountController'
        }
    }
})
.state('settings.account.person', {
    url: '/person',
    resolve: {
        languages: ['APIService',function(APIService) {
            return APIService.call(AppConfig.API_ENDPOINTS.language);
        }],
        data: ['menu','account','languages',function(menu,account,languages){
            return {
                menu: menu,
                account: account,
                languages: languages
            };
        }]
    }
    ,views: {
        'tabContent@settings.account': {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/settings/account/views/person.html'
            ,controller: 'AccountController'
        }
    }
})
.state('settings.account.password', {
    url: '/password'
    ,data: ['account',function(account){
        return {
            account: account
        };
    }]
    ,views: {
        'tabContent@settings.account': {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/settings/account/views/password.html'
            ,controller: 'AccountController'
        }
    }
})
.state('settings.account.delete', {
    url: '/delete'
    ,data: ['account',function(account){
        return {
            id: account.id
        };
    }]
    ,views: {
        'tabContent@settings.account': {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/settings/account/views/deleteAccount.html'
            ,controller: 'AccountController'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Currently your settings.account.password doesn't have a 'resolve', it has a 'data', which is slightly different. Change it to resolve and it'll probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.. I see that in states 'settings.account.password' and 'settings.account.delete' I forgot half of the resolve block.... No wonder it doesn't get hit.